# Cryptic-Crosswords (9 x 10)

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

### Clues

**Down**

> 1. By coincidence, a Santa staggered. (6)
> 2. Greek warrior's weightless jump. (7)
> 3. A fleet in turmoil: Muslim fast unfinished. (6)
> 4. Obstetrician assembly is an intense preoccupation. (9)
> 5. Wander off with ugliest rag gleefully hidden. (8)

**Across**

> 6. Fervor with alternative foetus for fanatics. (7)
> 7. Relationship between people is a science. (9)
> 8. Scorched roughly for a certain style! (6)
> 9. Revolutionary service level agreement initially introduced as a dance. (5)
> 10. Vegetable masterpiece? I can't breathe. (9)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the answers:

> 1. CASUAL (A + CLAUS scrambled)
>  2. HOPLITE (LITE + HOP)
>  3. ARMADA (RAMADAN - N, scrambled)
>  4. OBSESSION (OB + SESSION) 
>  5. STRAGGLE (uglieST RAG GLEefully)
>  6. ZEALOTS (ZEAL + fOeTuS)
>  7. CHEMISTRY (double def)
>  8. DESIGN (SINGED scrambled)
>  9. SALSA (S.L.A. + AS, scrambled)
>  10. ARTICHOKE (ART + I + CHOKE)